# how can i plot the graph for csv data in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

can you please tell me how to plot the graph for csv data. 
csv file have x,y,depth,color values i want to plot the depth and color for x and y axis,i goggled many times but i didn't find anything properly.so please guide me how to plot the graph for that values?
this is i tried :

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv("Tunnel.csv",names=['x','y','z','color'])
data1 =data[data.z==0]
print (data1)

# plt.plot(data[data.x],data[data.y])
plt.ylabel('yaxis')
plt.xlabel('xaxis')
plt.title('Tunnel 2d')
plt.show()
```

my data is given bellow
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want the first two columns to be used as plot axis and columns 3 and 4 as plot data.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("Tunnel.csv")

x = stats[stats.columns[2]]
y = stats[stats.columns[3]]

xlab = list(stats)[0]   #x-axis label
ylab = list(stats)[1]   #y-axis label

fig, pli = plt.subplots()
pli.show()

#Assuming it's a line graph that you want to plot
line, = pli.plot(x, y, color='g', linewidth=5, label='depth vs color')

plt.xlabel(xlab)
plt.ylabel(ylab)
plt.title(title)

fig.savefig('./Directory/Graph.png')
```

Comment: Thq so much sir i want a counter plot graph .when i run this program i got this error AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'show'

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want the color and depth as text annotations.

import stuff

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

create the df

```
dep=list(np.random.randint(0,100,10))
col=list(np.random.randint(0,100,10))
y=[int(x/3)+1 for x in range(0,10)]
x=list(range(0,10))
my_df=pd.DataFrame({'x':x,'y':y,'colour':col,'depth':dep})
```

create the annotate column

```
my_df['my_text']='c= '+my_df.colour.astype(str)+','+'d= '+my_df.depth.astype(str)
```

plot it

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.plot(my_df.x,my_df.y,'o')
for i, txt in enumerate(my_df['my_text']):
    plt.annotate(txt, (x[i],y[i]), size=10, xytext=(0,0), ha='left', textcoords='offset points', bbox=dict(facecolor='none', edgecolor='red'))

plt.ylabel('yaxis')
plt.xlabel('xaxis')
plt.title('Tunnel 2d')
plt.show()
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uxQ6.png)